# How to remove list element using while loop

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, for-loop, if-statement, while-loop

I open a web page to get the names of the cluster1(p1, p2). I am not sure how many times I need to open a web page to get these cluster1 names. So, I am using a while loop, it will remove the p1 or p2 whichever the value is obtained from web page.

When I open a web page, I'll get p1 or p2 and that value will be stored in new[-1]. If this value is in cluster1, it will execute the other test functions and that value will be removed from cluster1.

```
new = ['some',  'list' 'items', 'p1'] # last element of list is either p1 or p2. So, new[-1] will give p1 or p2.

cluster1 =[ 'p1', 'p2'] 

 while len(cluster1) != 0:
    print("Length of cluster1 before:", len(cluster1))
    # for i in range(10):

    if new[-1] in cluster1:
        print(new[-1] + " is in cluster1.")
        test1()
        test2()
        new_ver_names.append(new[-1])
        cluster1.remove(new[-1])
        print("Length of cluster1 after:", len(cluster1))
    else:
            print(new[-1] + " portal version is not listed.")
            driver.quit()
            break
```

My exception is, when value is removed, control should go back to while loop and start again until len(cluster1) is 0. And, if the value is not in cluster1, else past should execute. But, when I remove `cluster1.remove(new[-1])`, else part also gets executed.

I checked other answers where it is mentioned we can't remove items from a list while iterating over it and tried list comprehension. But, couldn't make it work.

I tried `lst = [(teset1(), test2()) for i in range(len(cluster1)) if new[-1] in cluster1]`

Any help is really appreciated.

Thank you.

Edit:

```
def login1():

ChromeDriver = 'C:\\PortalTesting\\Drivers\\chromedriver.exe'
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument("--incognito")

chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=1920x1080")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=ChromeDriver, chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(130)

driver.get("MY_URL")
print("session id ", driver.session_id)
username = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#uid")
username.send_keys("username")
password = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#pid")
password.send_keys("password")

login_button = driver.find_element_by_class_name("secondarybtnlabel")
login_button.click()
# time.sleep(10)
cluster1 = ['p1', 'p2']
dc_elm = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[4]/div/div[2]/span[2]').text
new = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', dc_elm).encode('ascii', 'ignore').split()
print("Portal version: ", new[-1])
logout_btn = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[4]/div[2]/div/div[4]/div/div[2]/div/header/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[3]/div/li')
logout_btn.click()

driver.delete_all_cookies()
print("Clearing cookies")
new_ver_names = []
time.sleep(3)

while len(cluster1) != 0:
    print("Length of cluster1 before:", len(cluster1))
    # for i in range(10):
    if new[-1] in cluster1:
        print(new[-1] + " is in cluster1.")
        test1()
        test2()

        new_ver_names.append(new[-1])

        # cluster1.remove(new[-1])
        print("Length of cluster1 after:", len(cluster1))
    else:
            print(new[-1] + " portal version is not listed.")
            driver.quit()
            break
        # cluster1.remove(new[-1])
```

Comment: It seems like you're doing a lot of stuff "manually". Can you please provide input and output samples more clearly? It is hard to understand what the code is doing at the moment.

Comment: @ReutSharabani, Here, input is new[-1], it will be p1 or p2. I need to make sure that web page displays p1 and p2(web page displays one value at a time. ) but, I am not sure how many times I need to open that web page. So, I am using while loop. Once, p1 or p2 is found, it will remove that values from cluster1 list.
Output: if the value new[-1] is in cluster1 list, run test1 and test2 otherwise, run else part.

Comment: "we can't remove items from a list while iterating over it " this is true but you are not iterating over the list (your loop is not "`for x in cluster1`") so it doesn't apply here.

Comment: @ReutSharabani,, I've updated my script

Answer (score 1):

It is hard (for me) to understand what happens in the current code, but why not try `set`s?

```
new = {'some',  'list' 'items', 'p1'}
cluster1 ={'p1', 'p2'}

in_both = new & cluster1
not_found = cluster1 - new

# do stuff with values in `in_both` and `not_found`....
```

Comment: I tried with     set but no luck. 
Above code is somewhat similar to this:
    def while_test1():
 b = [2,3,4]
 a = [4,3,2]
 c = []
 while len(b) != 0:

  if i in b:
   print(i , " is in b.")
   c.append(i)
   b.remove(i)
  else:
   print(i , "not in b.")
 print(c)


Output:
    (3, ' is in b.')
    (3, 'not in b.')
    (3, 'not in b.')
    (3, 'not in b.')
    (3, 'not in b.') ....  goes into infinite loop.

It removes the element from list and instead of going back to while it executes else part.

Comment: what is missing in what I wrote? Why do you need a loop? It makes things much more complicated.